# Laravel is not uploading images in online server

Tags: php, laravel, intervention

My laravel app is located outside "public_html" in "example" folder. The application is running as it was locally, except laravel is not uploading images. The is how my storage is configured in "config/filesystem.php" file

```
'disks' => [

    'local' => [
        'driver' => 'local',
        'root' => storage_path('app/public'),
    ],

    'public' => [
        'driver' => 'local',
        'root' => storage_path('app/public'),
        'url' => env('APP_URL').'/storage',
        'visibility' => 'public',
    ],
],
```

This is my code for image upload

```
protected function uploadImage($image, $path, $resizeX, $resizeY)
{        
    $ext = explode('.', $image->getClientOriginalName()); 
    $filename = md5(uniqid())."." . $ext[count($ext) -1];
    $image_resize = Image::make($image->getRealPath());           
    $image_resize->resize($resizeX, $resizeY, function ($constraint) {
        $constraint->aspectRatio();                 
    });
    $image_resize->stream(); 
    Storage::disk('local')->put($path.$filename, $image_resize, 'public');
    return 'storage/'.$path.$filename;
}
```

However if I upload the image manually to storage folder the symlink to public folder is working without problem. I am using Intervention for uploading images.

Comment: are you uploading through a form? did you check your post_max_size and upload_max_filesize in php.ini?

Comment: Those are working fine. Video and other file uploads are working.

Comment: This problem you faced for php version extension. Trying to updated your php version on server and allow the php extension while update your php version. I was also faced this prob. To use image:make()

Comment: Turned out I only needed to enable "fileinfo" from select php version